# How to automate DB setup of Entity Framework's Code First in Testcontainers for testing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, testcontainers

In order to setup the [Testcontainer](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet)'s [`MsSqlTestcontainer`](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mssqlserver/) for testing, I copied the script emitted by `dotnet ef migrations script` and planted it in the unit-test's setup (actual code doesn't :

```
void PrepareDb(MsSqlTestcontainer dbTestContainer){
    dbTestContainer.ExecScriptAsync(@"CREATE TABLE [DbName] ( /* ... */ )");
}
```

Is there a way to automate it, for instance if the DB model ever changes, and wire-up e.g. `MyDbContext` straight to the `Testcontainer`'s logic?

I was considering passing the `MyDbContext` code into the container and run `dotnet ef migrations script` inside of it, but I'm not sure how much it worth the effort (and I need to use a container that already has `dotnet` installed, which is another complication..).

That's the `dbTestContainer` setup, FWIW:

```
var dbTestContainer = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
    .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration { Password = "whatever secret" })
    .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge")
    .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer())
    .Build()
```

Comment: [2. Using .NET's hosted service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74969399/690017) shows how to create the database schema and seed data. This might work with the migration too. I haven't done a lot with EF in the past, but I will look into it and extend the example.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it, at least for my own basic needs. In case you still need a solution, here is what I did.

**Note: If anyone knows a better approach or spots any flaws below, I would be very happy to hear about it.**

I have a `IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory` which I use to do the usual configuration for my integration tests. As Pavel already pointed out, you can run the migrations programmatically before the tests start. For this,  my `IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory`implements the `IAsyncLifetime` interface of `XUnit`, which I am using for testing. This interface requires you to implement `InitializeAsync` and `DisposeAsync` methods. Inside of `InitializeAsync` I run the `await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();` command.

Here is the full code of my `IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory` class:

```
public class IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly TestcontainerDatabase _container;

    public IntegrationTestFactory()
    {
        _container = new TestcontainersBuilder<MsSqlTestcontainer>()
            .WithDatabase(new MsSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
            {
                Username = "sa",
                Database = "WeatherApp",
                Password = "2@LaiNw)PDvs^t>L!Ybt]6H^%h3U>M",
            })
            .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .Build();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DemoDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(_container.ConnectionString); });
        });
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await _container.StartAsync();
        using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DemoDbContext>();
        await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }

    public new async Task DisposeAsync() => await _container.DisposeAsync();
}
```

And this is how I used it in  my integration tests:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineAutoData]
    public async Task GettingWeatherForecastReturnsOkay(WeatherForecast expectedForecast)
    {
        var client = _integrationTestFactory.CreateClient();

        // insert into db what you want to assert
        await client.PostAsJsonAsync("WeatherForecast", expectedForecast);
        
        // read from db
        var forecasts = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<WeatherForecast>>("WeatherForecast");

        // do asserts or whatever..
        forecasts.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        forecasts.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expectedForecast);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the containerized database and run migrations programmatically before tests start with

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```