# Testcontainers: "Container %some_id% is not running", he has started but has exited

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, xunit, testcontainers

I already have a integration tests based on `inMemoryDatabase & XUnit`, so I decided to refactor it for docker images via [`testcontainers 3.5`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers). I tried to resolve it solo but run into a dead end.

The issue is at the heart of starting create container, for beginning you should create the configuration and the next realize `IAsyncLifetime`. After this steps just open the docker and the next running your tests, it's the basic, how to do it. After these steps I had two errors:

1. *`"System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out."`*. I do not know why, but it appeared in `XUnit` method `"CreateClassFixtureAsync(Type fixtureType)"` and dropped here:

   [image]
2. *`"Docker API responded with status code=Conflict, response={message:Container %some_id% is not running}"`* it happened because in Docker container at the same moment as starting has changed status to `Exited`.

   [image: the second container status is "Exited"]

   [image: Happened in StartAsync()]

My **`Factory.cs`** class that creates a container:

```
public class IntegrationTestApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{

    private const string ImageName = "ubuntu:16.04"; // tips #1
    private const string Database = "master";
    private const string Username = "sa";
    private const string Password = "myStr0ng!&Passw0rd!";
    private int MsSqlPort = Random.Shared.Next(10000, 60000);
    
    private readonly IContainer _mssqlContainer;
    
    public IntegrationTestMalumApplicationFactory()
    {
        _mssqlContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage(ImageName)
            .WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")
            .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDUSER", Username)
            .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDPASSWORD", Password)
            .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", Password)
            .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_PID", "Evaluation")
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(MsSqlPort))
            .WithPortBinding(MsSqlPort, true)
            .WithExposedPort(MsSqlPort)
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .Build();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var host = _mssqlContainer.Hostname;
        var port = _mssqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlPort);
        
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<DataAccess.Context>));

            services.AddDbContextPool<DataAccess.Context>((options, optionsBuilder) =>
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    $"Server={host},{port};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};TrustServerCertificate=true");
            });
        });
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync() => await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
    public async new Task DisposeAsync() => await _mssqlContainer.StopAsync();
}
```

My **`Test.cs`** looks like:

```
public class IntegrationTestMalumApi : IClassFixture<IntegrationTestApplicationFactory>
{
    protected readonly HttpClient TestClient;
    protected readonly ApplicationUrl ApplicationUrl;

    public IntegrationTestMalumApi(IntegrationTestApplicationFactory applicationFactory)
    {
        TestClient = applicationFactory.CreateClient();
        ApplicationUrl = new ApplicationUrl("http://localhost:1324");
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCats_WithThreeCats_ReturnHttpCodeOK()
    {
        // to do something
    }
}
```

**A few tips:**

1. tried to use `"mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04"` but it actually works only with existing `imageName`;
2. `ApplicationUrl` is the class that constaint routes for any API path;
3. The issue happened in `"CreateClassFixtureAsync(Type fixtureType)"` in the class `"XunitTestClassRunner.cs"`;
4. Some times it happened in `"InitializeAsync()"` in the class `"IntegrationTestApplicationFactory "` whenever it tried to use `"_mssqlContainer.StartAsync()";`
5. Whenever i tried something like `"IContainer container = new ContainerBuilder().WithImage(ImageName).Build()"` that use base configuration it does not work too.

**Question:** Do you have any tips what is it? and what I doing wrong?

Comment: Tip #5: whenever i tried something like "IContainer container = new ContainerBuilder().WithImage(ImageName).Build()" that use base configuration it does not work too.

Comment: If you have more to add to your question, please use the [edit] feature.

Comment: The `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` images listen on their tcp/1433 port and expose that. Have you tried using that instead of generating a random port number? `.WithPortBinding(MsSqlPort, true)` will generate its own random port number to bind to it from the Docker host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After answer by ***@AlwaysLearning***, i had reworked it.

**Solution:**

So, how he said the main reason was in port. Port for **MSSQL** should equals `"1433"` by default, it's a answer for my question, but not the end. The next i have received exception based on config, fix was the next string: `"ACCEPT_EULA=Y"`.

**Code looks next:**

```
private const string ImageName = "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04";
private const ushort MssqlPort = 1433;
private const string Database = "master";
private const string Username = "sa";
private const string Password = "myStr0ng!&Passw0rd!";
private const string ContainerName = "integrationtest";

private readonly IContainer _mssqlContainer;


public IntegrationTestApplicationFactory()
{
    _mssqlContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage(ImageName)
            .WithName(String.Concat(ContainerName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
            .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")
            .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDUSER", Username)
            .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDPASSWORD", Password)
            .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", Password)
            .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_PID", "Evaluation")
            .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(MssqlPort))
            .WithPortBinding(MssqlPort, true)
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .Build();
}
```

For more, i have reworked `InitializeAsync` method for create my EF migration, source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73790491/21142756):

```
public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
    
    using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();
    
    await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

**Useful links:**

1. [Which ports need to be opened in a firewall to access SQL server?](https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/Article/46522)
2. [How to find the port being used by SQL Server?](https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/articles/Article/39342)